# Why $g$ is not monotonic in any neighborhood of $0?$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

> Let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $g(x) :=x+ 2x ^ 2
>  \sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $g(0) := 0$. Show that $g'(0) =
>  1$, but in every neighborhood of $0$ the derivative $g'(x)$ takes on
>   both positive and negative values. Thus $g$ is not monotonic in any
>   neighborhood of $0$.

I could show that $g'(0)=1$. Why do $g$ is not monotonic in any
 neighborhood of $0$? Here, $g'(0)>0$. Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ differentiable function. Let $f'(c)>0$. Choose $\epsilon=\frac{f'(c)}{2}$;$\exists \delta>0:\forall x (0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)|<\frac{f'(c)}{2}).$ Re-arrangeing, $\forall x (0<|x-c|<\delta \implies \frac{f'(c)}{2}<\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}<3\frac{f'(c)}{2}).$ $i,e$ slope of the secant line is positive in some neighbourhood of $c$.ie function is increasing. right? Why it is not possible here? Please help me.

Comment: Note that $g'$ is not continuous at $0$. Its value at $0$ is $1$ as you say, but it oscillates approximately over all the values in $[1-2,1+2]=[-1,3]$ on every neighborhood of $0$ since away from $0$ one has $g'(x) = 1-2\cos\frac1x + 4\frac{sin\frac1x}{\frac1x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: The slope of every sufficiently short secant line (i.e., with end point in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $0$) starting at $(0,f(0))$ is positive. However, for $f$ to be increaing in a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, you need positive slope for any pair of endpoints in that $U$, not jsut those wit one end at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just compute the derivative.  For $x\neq0,$ we have $$f'(x)=1+4x\sin(1/x)-2\cos(1/x).$$  Now, $\lim_{x\to0}{1+4x\sin(1/x)}=1$ and we can choose $x$ so that $|1/x|$ is arbitrarily small and $2\cos(1/x)=\pm2,$ so that $f'(x)$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Typo: middle term should be $4x\sin\frac1x$

Comment: @MPW Thanks, I'll fix it.